# error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::__cxx11::string&)'

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a program that opens a file and counts the whitespace-separated words in that file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filepath;
    cout << "Enter the file path including the file name:" << endl;
    cin >> filepath; 
    ifstream f(filepath);
    int nwords = 0;
    string word;
    while (f >> word)
        ++nwords;
    cout << "Number of words = " << nwords << endl;
}
```

This is the error when I try to compile it.

```
g++ Assignment1.cpp
Assignment1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Assignment1.cpp:10:21: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::__cxx11::string&)'
  ifstream f(filepath);
                     ^
In file included from Assignment1.cpp:2:0:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:495:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       basic_ifstream(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:495:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:481:7: note: candidate: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
       basic_ifstream() : __istream_type(), _M_filebuf()
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:481:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:455:11: note: candidate: std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)
     class basic_ifstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\fstream:455:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const std::basic_ifstream<char>&'
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11` or higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g++ -std=c++11 Assignment1.cpp
```

Should work. The problem is there's different standards for C++ over the years. Standards get mixed. 90% of errors you see at compile time that have anything to do with ios in it, in my experience have either been compiled with gcc or the standard is wrong. Sorry I can't be sure though; I don't use windows.

Comment: Thank you. That got me compiling correctly. But now I don't get the results I wanted.  Any ideas?
C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive\TMA1>a.exe
Enter the file path including the file name:
C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive\TMA1\Assignment1.cpp

Number of words = 0

Comment: Close the file after you are done using the file. It's just a good habit but it's causing the problem. In C++ and other languages there are special characters, these are identified by a backslash and a character. So to get a backslash in a string it's actually a double backslash. Try entering the file name in one of these two ways.                          
              C:/Users/SuperUser/Google Drive/TMA1/Assignment1.cpp                                  
              C:\\Users\\SuperUser\\Google Drive\\TMA1\\Assignment1.cpp

Comment: Still nothing.
C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive\TMA1>a.exe
Enter the file path including the file name:
C:\\Users\\SuperUser\\Google Drive\\TMA1\\Assignment1.cpp
Number of words = 0

Comment: C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive\TMA1>a.exe
Enter the file path including the file name:
C:/Users/SuperUser/Google Drive/TMA1/Assignment1.cpp
Number of words = 0

Comment: I'm going to assume that the file is in the same directory as the executable based off how you compiled it and it being the source file to the executable. I don't know why it might not be working, but it looks like a MingW to me, but can you try one more thing for me and tell me what you get? Try entering the file as Assignment1.cpp instead of the exact path. That should give you 54 for sure.

Comment: That worked :) C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive\TMA1>a.exe
Enter the file path including the file name:
Assignment1.cpp
Number of words = 54
I am still not quite sure why the full path didn't work.

Comment: It's the space in Google Drive. Might need some quotes around it but again I don't use windows cmd so I couldn't tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename.append(".txt");
file.open(filename.c_str());
```

works in my case

Comment: You don't need to use `c_str()` here since C++11.